# Using "you know" when the listener can't be expected to know.

Tags: word-usage, sentence, filler-words

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Garbage/stuff words](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/20424/garbage-stuff-words)

Can you end a sentence with "you know," when telling the listener some new information that they couldn't possibly be expected to know?

For example, you could tell someone something like, "I'm actually quite good at this, you know." Now that I think about it, it wouldn't seem normal to say this if they already did know. It seems backwards.

So what's up with this?

Comment: Also related: [How to use “You know”?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/7297/how-to-use-you-know), [“Well” as an introduction to an argument](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/15136/well-as-an-introduction-to-an-argument), [Why am I always compelled to begin a response with “Well, ”?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/674/why-am-i-always-compelled-to-begin-a-response-with-well)

Answer (score 3):

I would say *you know* is a “tag” that allows the speaker to seek confirmation from the listener, or at least suggest they are seeking it.

*I've been on a strict diet. You know, lots of vegetables, run every day.*

*Their third album was much more intimate than their fourth, you know?*

It performs a similar role to *yeah?* or *you know what I mean?*